# Matplotlib: Discrete colorbar fails for custom labels

Tags: matplotlib

I faced a serious problem when I was trying to add colorbar to scatter plot which indicates in which classes individual sample belongs to. The code works perfectly when classes are [0,1,2] but when the classes are for example [4,5,6] chooses colorbar automatically color values in the end of colormap and colorbar looks blue solid color. I'm missing something obvious but I just can't figure out what it is.

***Here is the example code about the problem:***

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1 , figsize=(6, 6))
plt.scatter(datapoints[:,0], datapoints[:,1], s=20, c=labels, cmap='jet', alpha=1.0)
plt.setp(ax, xticks=[], yticks=[])
cbar = plt.colorbar(boundaries=np.arange(len(classes)+1)-0.5)
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(len(classes)))
cbar.set_ticklabels(classes)
plt.show()
```

Variables can be for example

```
datapoints = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7]])
labels = np.array([4,5,6,4,5,6,4])
classes = np.array([4,5,6])
```

Correct result is got when

```
labels = np.array([0,1,2,0,1,2,0])
```

In my case I want it to work also for classes [4,5,6]

Comment: Things work fine if you remove `boundaries=np.arange(len(classes)+1)-0.5`

Comment: I tried that but colorbar is not discrete anymore and set_ticklabels does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buoundaries` need to be in data units. Meaning, if your classes are `4,5,6`, you probably want to use boundaries of `3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

datapoints = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7]])
labels = np.array([4,5,6,4,5,6,4])
classes = np.array([4,5,6])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1 , figsize=(6, 6))
sc = ax.scatter(datapoints[:,0], datapoints[:,1], s=20, c=labels, cmap='jet', alpha=1.0)
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=classes, boundaries=np.arange(4,8)-0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you wanted to have the boundaries determined automatically from the classes, some assumption must me made. E.g. if all classes are subsequent integers,

```
boundaries=np.arange(classes.min(), classes.max()+2)-0.5
```

In general, an alternative would be to use a `BoundaryNorm`, as shown e.g. in [Create a discrete colorbar in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360879/create-a-discrete-colorbar-in-matplotlib/53361072#53361072)
or [How to specify different color for a specific year value range in a single figure? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869328/how-to-specify-different-color-for-a-specific-year-value-range-in-a-single-figur/46873370#46873370) or [python colormap quantisation (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191857/python-colormap-quantisation-matplotlib/53192170#53192170)

Comment: What about if classes are [4,6,7]? Could one option to replace labels with low values and define new labels for color information in scatter plot?

Comment: It actually worked by replacing color information with np.unique(z, return_inverse=True)[1].tolist(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: `np.unique(z, return_inverse=True)[1].tolist()` maps the classes to successive integer numbers. That is sufficiently different from what I'm proposing here and more similar to the linked answers using a boundary norm, to either deserve its own answer. No need to accept this one if at the end you use a different solution; but showing that solution to others (here `z` isn't even defined`) in a new answer would make sense.

Comment: For me this answer helped to figure out what is it all about and I will accept the answer